# How to test the accuracy in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm a newbie in R and statistics and I don't know how to test if the participants of my experiment are more accurate in one condition or in the other.

This is the problem: 
Let's suppose I test participants in two experimental conditions, A and B. I simply need to verify if they are more correct in the A or B condition.

```
subject <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
condition <- c("A","B","A","B","A","B")
error <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1)

data <- cbind(subject, condition, error)
```

Do I have to use logit regression? And How I can implement that in R?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a programming question. If you need help choosing the appropriate statistical analysis method for your data, you should ask your question at [stats.se]. You should first know what you want to do before you ask how to do it "in R." Have you tried googling logit regression in R if that's what you want to do? Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in which group (A or B) has lower average error and do not want to make a statement about the significance of the difference or the role of an individual:

```
mean(error[condition == "A"])

# 0.6666667

mean(error[condition == "B"])

# 0.3333333
```